# Javascript mobile commands

Tags: javascript, html

I came across a post here about initiating a telephone call from mobile device through JavaScript where command goes like `href='tel:88823'` or `window.open("tel:727323")`. I didn't know native JavaScript had these kind of commands or abilities to access device features. Is this with some kind of library or where can I get document for these command lists. Thanks.

Comment: This is not a javascript functionality. It's just a pseudo-prototocol implemented by some browsers, similar to `ftp:` or `http:` or whatever they support.

Comment: thanks for clarifying, had the same assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can trigger a call (or  a popup asking if you want to call depending on the device) with:

```
<a href="tel:07733255493">07733255493</a>
```

This is a feature of the device, not of javascript. There is no javascript being used here, just html and the devices handling of that notation/syntax.

(in the same way that `<a href="mailto:me@hello.com">email me</a>` triggers your email client, of using `javascript:` allows you to call a js function)

Here is a [good blog post](https://beradrian.wordpress.com/2010/01/15/special-links/) about all the other types of links you can have including `skype:`, `sms:` and `geopoint:`